# XSLT for-each logic with multiple conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to filter xml and recreate a separate output message using XSLT

**Input Message**

```
<header1>
<tag1>abc</tag1>
<tag2 attr1="test">bcd</tag2>
<tag4>
        <aa>aaaaaa</aa>
        <bb>
            <c attr1="value1">Hello</c>
            <c attr1="value2">test111</c>
            <c attr1="value3">test222</c>
        </bb>
    </tag4>
    <tag4>
        <aa>aaaaaa</aa>
        <bb>
            <c attr1="value1">YYYY</c>
            <c attr1="value2">test1122</c>
            <c attr1="value3">test000</c>
        </bb>
    </tag4>
    <tag4>
        <aa>aaaaaa</aa>
        <bb>
            <c attr1="value1">Hello</c>
            <c attr1="value2">test111</c>
            <c attr1="value3">testxxx</c>
        </bb>
</tag4>
</header1>
```

**Expected Message**

```
"out" : {
"a" : "abc",
"xx" : [
{"got" : "test222"},
{"got" : "testxxx"}
]
}
```

**Filtering Logic**

XX tag should be populated based on the following logic.

- tag4/aa = "aaaaaa"
- tag4/bb/c[@attr1=value1]=Hello
- tag4/bb/c[@attr1=value2]=test1122

**Implemented filtering logic**

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tag4[aa='aaaaaa' and bb/c[@attr1='value1']='Hello' and bb/c[@attr1='value2']='test111']">
</xsl:for-each>
```

None of the element goes inside to this for each logic. Is there any issue in this logic

Comment: You've got a small typo in your expression. You are checking for `aaaaa` (which is five characters long), but in your logic you say you want `aaaaaa` (which is six).

Comment: I fixed that typo issue. but I'm getting the same issue

Comment: I think you may need to show more of your XSLT, because your actual logic seems fine. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMN for a minimal example. Thank you.

Comment: Does your actual XML have a default namespace declaration on it, by any chance, of the form `xmlns="..."`?

Comment: XSLT is not the best language to create JSON. Many of the JSON rules (for example "no newline characters allowed in strings") are not handled, which means you run the risk of producing syntactically invalid JSON. Consider using a different language to process the XML (unless you want to implement all the JSON-specific output rules yourself).

Comment: @Tomalak, in XSLT 3 and XPath 3.1 you have support to transform/map XML to JSON with awareness of JSON output rules e.g. with XML like `<root><items><item>Line 1.&#10;Line 2.&#10;"Quoted Line 3."&#10;Line 4.</item></items></root>` an XPath expression like `serialize(doc('input.xml')//items!array { item ! map { local-name() : data() }},  map { 'method' : 'json' })` gives you JSON `[{"item":"Line 1.\nLine 2.\n\"Quoted Line 3.\"\nLine 4."}]`. So while I don't want to engage in any "best language to.." discussions I wouldn't rule out XSLT  for XML to JSON transformation in the presence of XSLT 3.

Comment: You're right, when XSLT 3+ is available and used correctly, this is not an issue anymore.

Comment: There was a namespace issue. Thanks you all.